# free basic compiler error 23: File not found, libsupc++.a

Tags: compiler-errors, ubuntu-12.04, qbasic, freebasic

I am trying to compile a simple a hello world QBASIC program in ubutu 12.04. Compiler is downloaded and installed as instructed here. http://www.freebasic.net/get

Also I posted it on askubuntu.com https://askubuntu.com/questions/226084/free-basic-compiler-error-23-file-not-found-libsupc-a#comment279100_226084 but reported to post here. Here is my simple QBASIC program and compilation details.

```
print "hello word"
```

I compiled it with

```
fbc hello.bas
```

But I got the following error.

```
hello.bas() error 23: File not found, libsupc++.a

ld: cannot find -lncurses ld: cannot find -lsupc++
```

Answer (score 1):

Your system lacks dependencies required by `fbc`. At least one package is missing. `libsupc++` is part of `libstdc++` which is installed when installing `g++`.

Have a look at the list at http://www.freebasic.net/wiki/wikka.php?wakka=CompilerInstalling

On Ubuntu you will need at least these packages:

- gcc, g++
- libncurses5-dev
- libx11-dev, libxext-dev, libxrender-dev, libxrandr-dev, libxpm-dev
- libffi-dev

You can install them using `apt-get` or `aptitude` or a GUI package management tool of your choice.