# test.bas() error 23: File not found

Tags: compiler-errors, freebasic

I'm trying to run a simple FreeBASIC program:

```
Print "Hello World"
```

However when I try to run it, it gives me these errors:

```
yamboy1@laptop:~$ fbc test.bas
test.bas() error 23: File not found, crt1.o
test.bas() error 23: File not found, crti.o
test.bas() error 23: File not found, crtn.o
ld: cannot find -lncurses
ld: cannot find -lm
ld: cannot find -ldl
ld: cannot find -lpthread
ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
ld: cannot find -lgcc
ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc_eh.a when searching for -lgcc_eh
ld: cannot find -lgcc_eh
ld: cannot find -lc
```

This is not the same as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757506/free-basic-compiler-error-23-file-not-found-libsupc-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a 32-bit / 64-bit mismatch, as if ld is looking for a 32-bit gcc toolchain. Did you by chance install the 32-bit FreeBasic?

It seems you are on a 64-bit machine, so if you did, try grabbing and installing the 64-bit version from:

`https://sourceforge.net/projects/fbc/files/Binaries%20-%20Linux/FreeBASIC-1.05.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz/download`

Answer (score 0):

The developing library is missing  you have to install the developing library before.

Be sure the FreeBASIC that you have downloaded is correct version
Under Shell Type

## uname -a

Where you can see the linux version if 32bit or 64bit
The download the correct FreeBASIC version.

For install all dependence on Debian and Ubuntu type under shell this command:

## sudo apt-get install gcc g++ libncurses5-dev libx11-dev libxext-dev libxpm-dev libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev